# How can I better build this SQL query without an extra AND in the end

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, postgresql

I am trying to build a SQL string dynamically, for example:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE A = B AND C = D AND E = F AND"
```

How can I better build this SQL query without an extra AND in the end?

My code:

```
let where = "";
if (_conditions.length > 0) {
   where = "WHERE ";
   for (let i = 0; i < _conditions.length; i++) {
     let curr_cond = _conditions[i];
     let keys = Object.keys(curr_cond);
     where += keys[0] + " = '" + curr_cond[keys[0]] + "' AND ";
}}
```

Comment: Maybe a better question would be "How can I better build this SQL query without an extra AND in the end?" :) How are you building it?

Comment: a little more information is needed for this question

Comment: If you are going to change the question, you will need to show some code how you are doing it.

Comment: i would assume it's being built with a loop of some kind. Maybe don't?

Comment: Currently, I am concatenating the strings together, quite manually, but has no better idea

Comment: Add the code that creates the query, because clearly the code is what we need to see. Also, why not simply use something like `conditions.join(" AND ")`?

Comment: Try something like `[ "A=B", "C=D", "E=F" ].join(" AND ")`, it'll give you `A=B AND C=D AND E=F`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're building up the WHERE clause using a loop.
It would be more elegant to use some kind of a String join.

In most languages, there's a way to join together a bunch of string values with a "separator".
For example in Java:

```java
List<String> conditions = List.of("A = B","C = D","E = F");
String whereClause = String.join(" AND ",conditions);
```

Or in Python:

```py
conditions = ['A = B', 'C = D', 'E = F']
whereclause = ' AND '.join(conditions)
```

Or in Javascript:

```js
var _conditions = ["A = B", "C = D", "E = F"];
var whereClause = _conditions.join(" AND ");
```

You probably don't even need to check the length of the list; an empty list or a list of one item won't include the separator.